# Mask of layer mask. Core animation

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-animation

I deep into the Core Animation and have some problem with layer masking

I try to make a complex UI layer with transparent things for study reasons

This view a have and put into the `ViewController`

```
public class TestView : UIView
    {
        public TestView()
        {
            Layer.Delegate = this;
            Frame = new CGRect(100f,200f, 100f, 100f);
        }

        public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
        {
            base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer(layer);

            var bounds = Bounds;
            var circleFrame = new CGRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
            var imageFrame = new CGRect(30, 30, 40, 40);

            Layer.BorderWidth = 5;
            Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
            Layer.CornerRadius = 4;

            var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradientLayer.Colors = new[] { UIColor.Green.CGColor, UIColor.Red.CGColor };
            gradientLayer.Frame = bounds;
            Layer.AddSublayer(gradientLayer);

            var maskOfGradientLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
            var path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(circleFrame, 30);
            path.UsesEvenOddFillRule = true;
            maskOfGradientLayer.Path = path.CGPath;
            maskOfGradientLayer.FillRule = CAShapeLayer.FillRuleEvenOdd;
            maskOfGradientLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            maskOfGradientLayer.Frame = bounds;
            gradientLayer.Mask = maskOfGradientLayer;

            var maskOfMaskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
            maskOfMaskLayer.Frame = imageFrame;
            maskOfMaskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            maskOfMaskLayer.Contents = Bundles.ImageOff.CGImage;

            Layer.AddSublayer(maskOfMaskLayer);
        }
    }
```

And that I have and this is exactly what I wanted.

[image]

But I also want can to make transparent in circle instead black color.

I tried to make like this `maskOfGradientLayer.Mask = maskOfMaskLayer.`
But this way `maskOfMaskLayer` do nothing! It's not working like mask must do. 
What I should to do?

Comment: Seems, Core Animation support only one level deep for set mask property

Comment: Who want to know more.
Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132875/animate-the-mask-of-a-mask-of-a-calayer

Comment: do you test  `maskOfMaskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;` instead of ` maskOfMaskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;` ??

Comment: @mohsen yes, I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All needed to do it is reverse image colors via Core Graphics, any color to transparent, transparent to any color. In this case, black color is enough

```
public static UIImage GetRevertImage(UIImage image, CGRect rect, CGRect cropFrame)
{
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.Size, false, 1);
    UIColor.Black.SetColor();
    UIGraphics.RectFill(rect);
    image.Draw(cropFrame, CGBlendMode.DestinationOut, 1);

    var newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

And set mask of mask layer to parent layer

`Layer.Mask = maskOfMaskLayer;`

And final version of code:

```
public class TestView : UIView
{
    public TestView()
    {
        Layer.Delegate = this;
        Frame = new CGRect(50f, 50f, 100f, 100f);
    }

    public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
    {
        base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer(layer);

        var bounds = Bounds;
        var circleFrame = new CGRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
        var imageFrame = new CGRect(30, 30, 40, 40);

        Layer.BorderWidth = 5;
        Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
        Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

        var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
        gradientLayer.Colors = new[] {UIColor.Green.CGColor, UIColor.Red.CGColor};
        gradientLayer.Frame = bounds;
        Layer.AddSublayer(gradientLayer);

        var maskOfGradientLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
        var path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(circleFrame, 30);
        path.UsesEvenOddFillRule = true;
        maskOfGradientLayer.Path = path.CGPath;
        maskOfGradientLayer.FillRule = CAShapeLayer.FillRuleEvenOdd;
        maskOfGradientLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        maskOfGradientLayer.Frame = bounds;
        gradientLayer.Mask = maskOfGradientLayer;

        var maskOfMaskLayer = new CALayer();
        maskOfMaskLayer.Frame = bounds;
        var image = UIImage.FromBundle("Turn");
        var reversedImage = GetReverseImage(image, bounds, imageFrame);
        maskOfMaskLayer.Contents = reversedImage.CGImage;

        Layer.Mask = maskOfMaskLayer;
    }

    private static UIImage GetReverseImage(UIImage image, CGRect rect, CGRect cropFrame)
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.Size, false, 1);
        UIColor.Black.SetColor();
        UIGraphics.RectFill(rect);
        image.Draw(cropFrame, CGBlendMode.DestinationOut, 1);
        var newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

[image: Final version]

Answer (score 0):

> But I also want can to make transparent in circle instead black color.

**Solution Exploratory Version:**

You can also use **UIBezierPath** to draw what you want, and set to `maskOfMaskLayer`:

```
var maskOfMaskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
maskOfMaskLayer.Frame = imageFrame;
maskOfMaskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
maskOfMaskLayer.Contents = Bundles.ImageOff.CGImage;

Layer.AddSublayer(maskOfMaskLayer);
```

Up code repalced with follow:

```
UIBezierPath offCirclePath = new UIBezierPath();

// draw an arc
offCirclePath.AddArc(new CGPoint(50, 50), circleFrame.Width / 3, (nfloat)(1.75 * Math.PI), (nfloat)(1.25 * Math.PI), true);

//draw a line
offCirclePath.MoveTo(new CGPoint(50, 30));
offCirclePath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(50, 45));

//set to maskOfMaskLayer 
var maskOfMaskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
maskOfMaskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
maskOfMaskLayer.Path = offCirclePath.CGPath;
maskOfMaskLayer.LineWidth = 5;
maskOfMaskLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
maskOfMaskLayer.LineCap = new NSString("round");

Layer.AddSublayer(maskOfMaskLayer);
```

Other code not changed.

[image]

> But I from starts thought about setting any custom image.

**Solution Two:**(Wrong direction)

I have tested that `CAShapeLayer` can not have this function to change color from image. [CAShapeLayer Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoMac.CoreAnimation.CAShapeLayer/)

However , I found `UIImageView` Can do that.There is a `TintColor` propert of it.This property is from UiView .[UIView.TintColor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiview.tintcolor?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UIView_TintColor).

[image]

```
var maskOfMaskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
maskOfMaskLayer.Frame = imageFrame;
maskOfMaskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
maskOfMaskLayer.Contents = Bundles.ImageOff.CGImage;

Layer.AddSublayer(maskOfMaskLayer);
```

Change to:

```
UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView();
imageView.Frame = imageFrame;
imageView.Image = Bundles.ImageOff;
imageView.TintColor = UIColor.White;

AddSubview(imageView);
```

[image]

**Right Solution** :

Sorry for misunderstanding the real want effect,I update as follow:

```
Layer.Mask = maskOfMaskLayer;
```

[image]

If you use `AddSublayer` just overwrite your image on the Layer, and `Layer.Mask` is the opposite effect, it only shows the background that covers the part, and the rest of the area will be white.[CALayer.Mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coreanimation.calayer.mask?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#CoreAnimation_CALayer_Mask)

Comment: Thanks a lot for great sample. But I from starts thought about setting any custom image.

Comment: @Asura Yeah, you can share sample project with custom image.I will check it.

Comment: @Asura I have tested my custom image . Unfortunately, if using `CAShapeLayer` can not modify this color.However , if using `UIImageView`, it can do that.I have updated answer.

Comment: And then we lost transparent color. Actually I solved this problem recently.
Instead of  ```Layer.AddSublayer(maskOfMaskLayer);``` 
must be ```Layer.Mask = maskOfMaskLayer;```

Comment: @Asura I am glad that you solved it. I think I misunderstood the effect you really wanted. I updated the effect you want in the answer. *.^

Comment: Sorry for was missed attention for this question. I have made final answer with correct code and result. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @Asura Glad to be helpful. :)